# Question when using sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: cart, entropy

`sklearn`'s `DecisionTreeClassifier` is not behaving as I expected. From the following:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
y = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
entropy_y      =  -1/2 * np.log2(0.5) + (-1/2) * np.log2(0.5)
cond_entropy_y =   1/2 * 1 + 0.25 * 0 + 0.25 * 0
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=1)
fit_tree = tree_classifier.fit(x, y)
```

I thought the first tree branch would make a decision where `X < 1.0`, since entropy would be `entropy_y` - `cond_entropy_y` = 0.5, which would give its maximum info gain.

However, I actually get `X < 1.5` for the first branch. Where am I mistaken? Entropy in that case is showing 0.918 for 6 samples, 0 for the rest 2 samples. How is this a maximum information gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `x < 1`, your child sets would be $C_1=[0,0,0,0]$ and $C_2=[1,1,2,2]$. In $C_1$, you've 2 samples from class 0, and two samples from class 1; which yields entropy $1$. In $C_2$, the situation is same. You have no information gain.

When `x < 1.5` is applied, one child's entropy is $0.918$ as you stated (6 samples);  and the other has $0$ entropy. The average entropy is $0.688$. Your information gain is $0.312$.

Comment: I finally see my simple blind math mistake. Thanks